# Can be setup Two domains emails for two customers in one exchange server?

Tags: email, exchange-server-2010

I have 1 server with 1 domain controller (abc.com). And I setup Microsoft exchange 2010 in this server. So no I need setup 2 difference email domain in this server (@abc.com and @def.com) for 2 customer independence (email @abc.com don't have any relationship with domain @def.com).

Can I setup my server like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is called multi-tennant Exchange, if I am reading your question correctly. It sounds like you're trying to manage multiple clients in the one server and not have them see each other in address books, GALs, contact lists, etc.

Yes, it's possible and not hard to do. You can either a) buy a product to manage it for you (based on an annual cost plus a cost per user) or just do it for free in powershell.

Please Google "powershell multitenant exchange" and you will find what you're looking for. There's a lot of steps and too many for a simple post on stackexchange but it's not a difficult task, assuming you are a reasonably competent Exchange admin.

In short. Make a new OU in AD called "tenants" or something like that. Let's assume your existing AD environment is "existing.com". And we're going to add "client1.com" to it, seperate from existing users or other tenants.

Now go into powershell (exchange obviously):

```
#***********CREATE THE NEW ACTIVE DIRECTORY CONTAINERS
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name client1 -Path "OU=Tenants,DC=existing,DC=com"
Set-ADForest -Identity existing.com -UPNSuffixes @{add="client1.com"}

#**********CREATE THE ACCEPTED DOMAIN NAME(S) FOR EMAILS (ADD BELOW AS REQUIRED)
New-AcceptedDomain -Name "client1.com" -DomainName client1.com -DomainType:Authoritative

 #**********CREATE THE  UNIQUE GAL & ADDRESS BOOKS
 New-GlobalAddressList -Name "client1 – GAL" -ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "client1" -IncludedRecipients MailboxUsers -RecipientContainer "existing.com/Tenants/client1"
New-OfflineAddressBook -Name "client1" -AddressLists "client1 – GAL"

#**********CREATE THE  UNIQUE GROUPS (rooms, users, etc)
New-AddressList -Name "client1 – All Rooms" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute1 -eq 'client1') -and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox')" -RecipientContainer "existing.com/Tenants/client1"
New-AddressList -Name "client1 – All Users" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute1 -eq 'client1') -and (ObjectClass -eq 'User')" -RecipientContainer "existing.com/Tenants/client1"
New-AddressList -Name "client1 – All Contacts" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute1 -eq 'client1') -and (ObjectClass -eq 'Contact')" -RecipientContainer "existing.com/Tenants/client1"
New-AddressList -Name "client1 – All Groups" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute1 -eq 'client1') -and (ObjectClass -eq 'Group')" -RecipientContainer "existing.com/Tenants/client1"

#**********CREATE THE EMAIL ADDRESS POLICIES UNIQUE TO THE CLIENT
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name "client1 – EAP" -RecipientContainer "existing.com/Tenants/client1" -IncludedRecipients "AllRecipients" -ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "client1" -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates "SMTP:%m@client1.com","smtp:%g.%s@client1.com","smtp:%g@client1.com"
Set-EmailAddressPolicy -Identity "client1 – EAP" -EnabledPrimarySMTPAddressTemplate "SMTP:%g@client1.com"
New-AddressBookPolicy -Name "client1" -AddressLists "client1 – All Users", "client1 – All Contacts", "client1 – All Groups" -GlobalAddressList "client1 – GAL" -OfflineAddressBook "client1" -RoomList "client1 – All Rooms"

#**********CREATE THEM A MEETING ROOM TO SHARE
New-Mailbox -Name 'client1 meeting' -Alias 'client1_meeting' -OrganizationalUnit 'existing.com/Tenants/client1' -UserPrincipalName 'meetingroom@client1.com' -SamAccountName 'client1_meeting' -FirstName 'Meeting' -LastName 'Room' -AddressBookPolicy 'client1' -Room
Set-Mailbox client1_meeting -CustomAttribute1 'client1'
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity client1_meeting -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept -DeleteComments $true -AddOrganizerToSubject $true -AllowConflicts $false

#**********SET A TEMP PASSWORD (later on, change it and set the user's password to never expire. I'll put the powershell to do that in later. For now, just use the GUI.
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
mysupersecretpassword

New-Mailbox -Name 'Homer Simpsons' -Alias 'client1_arim' -OrganizationalUnit 'existing.com/Tenants/client1' -UserPrincipalName 'homer@client1.com' -SamAccountName 'client1_homer' -FirstName 'Homer' -LastName 'Simpson' -Password $password -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false -AddressBookPolicy 'client1'
Set-ADUser -Identity client1_arim -PasswordNeverExpires $true

#**********TAG THE NEWLY CREATED MAILBOXES TO THE CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE, SO enter code hereTHEY CAN SEE EACH OTHER, GET THEIR GAL, BOOKS, ETC.
Set-Mailbox client1_homer -CustomAttribute1 "client1"
```

Job done. Now you have a new tenant who is hidden from your other tenants. Repeat this process for each tenant.

Needless to say, you can not use the GUI to manage users from now on, either - you'll need to use powershell and remember to assign users, groups, aliases, contacts, etc to tenants, or they won't be visible to them (or worse yet, visible to the wrong group).

Final word - the above powershell is all tested and functional on Exchange 2013. I am assuming it's ok on 2010 but there might be minor tweaks for 2010.

Comment: I created the OU with name SPWEB OU in active directory, but I don't understand this step: "Let's assume your existing AD environment is "existing.com". And we're going to add "client1.com" to it". I cannot find where to add client1.com